# Is there a "plug and play" approach for Laravel modules?

Tags: php, laravel, module

I have a question, I am still getting to grips with Laravel (came over from CI)
I'm looking to implement modules into my application in a similar style to say, wordpress plugins. I took a look at some of the HMVC libraries available but they all seem to require you to explicitly declare each service in the app/config/app.php

I'm wondering if there's a more plug and play approach I can take, where I am able to drop in a folder and it works off the bat, is there an appropriate way to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "drop in folder and it just works" solution for Laravel, but Packages is probably the closest to what you are describing:

http://laravel.com/docs/packages

Usually after you install a package, you run an `artisan` command to publish configurations and potentially run some database migrations, and then you're good to go.

I would start there if you want to create some additional self-contained functionality without wading into the existing site..

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Laravel 5 package that manages modules. You can "drop in folder and it just works".

There is also a artisan module generator.

[l5-modular](https://packagist.org/packages/artem-schander/l5-modular) have fun, save some time ;)